# Returning by reference versus by value. C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

In what situation would generate an error if you don't return something by reference for a function?

Comment: Assignment operators http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/assignment-operators.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In what situation would generate an error if you don't return something by reference for a function?**

Restricting the answer to what is being exactly asked,
Whenever you want the return value of the function to act as an l-value, and you do not return by reference then it will generate an error.

The more common example of this is overloading the `operator []`(the array subscription operator), You have to return by reference in order to use the `[]` on the l.h.s or more correctly to use it as an l-value.

**[An example](http://ideone.com/mVYb8)**:

```
class Myclass 
{ 
     int i;
     public:
     /*Not returned by reference- gives error*/
     int operator[](int idx){ return i;}

     /*Returned by reference- gives no error*/
     //int& operator[](int idx){ return i;}
};

int main()
{
   Myclass  obj;
   obj[1]= 10;
   return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

> prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
>   prog.cpp:16: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Comment: My Vector class did have a subscript operator that I overloaded and it does make sense that returning by reference is necessary if you are trying to assign a certain element of the Vector a value.  Like if I were to try a[0] = 1, returning a value wouldn't work because it would compare the value inside a[0] (ex. 3) to the 1, making it 3=1 which doesn't make sense.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The question should be when is it not safe to return by reference. Whenever you return a variable local to a method by reference, you're invoking undefined behavior.

It's unsafe to return by value when you haven't correctly implemented the copy constructor.

You'd get an error if copy constructor was declared private and you'd try to return by value.

Comment: Indeed. It's less of a case of 'what would generate an error' and more a case of in what situations should I return by reference. Places where, in c, you would be using a pointer are places where a reference _could_ be used.

Comment: The Q is clear and concise & this does not answer the question being asked.The answer makes an important point but it is completely irrelevant to what was asked.

Comment: @Als doesn't the second paragraph answer the question - "In what situation would generate an error if you don't return something by reference for a function?" - not implementing the c-ctor.

Comment: Not implementing the copy constructor doesn't give an error, the compiler implicitly generates one. And *"correctly implemented copy constructor"* leaves a lot of ambiguity in what it means,the Q asks a scenario that would generate a error, an improperly implemented c-ctor(not following Rule of Three etc) will end up giving an Undefined Behavior and most likely a segmenation fault but not an compilation error as the Q asks.

Comment: @Als ok, I didn't assume it was a compiler error, since the op didn't specify that. Nonetheless I edited - if you make the c-ctor private you'll get a compiler error. Anyway, IMO, you use the downvote button too freely.

Comment: Yes,I do use the downvote button freely on wrong answers, that is the very purpose of the downvote button.

Comment: @Als of course, I'm not questioning the right to downvote. But I don't see how this, esp after the edit, is wrong...

Answer (score 2):

The default action should be to return by value.  The main case where
you'ld want to return a reference is when you want to expose some
“part” of a larger object; e.g. an element in a vector or a
map.  The important thing is that the object referred to must have a
lifetime beyond that of the calling function.